# localStorage getItem issue

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have multiple inputs on my page and store the data from them inside < span > ... < /span > by button click (since the text is typed and stored, it is considered not to disappear from those < span > fields).

```
        var newDate = document.getElementById('event_date');//my input
        var storageNewDate = newDate.value;//my text inside <input> which transfers it to <span>
        localStorage.setItem('Date', storageNewDate);//the data is stored
```

But I can't retrieve the stored data from localStorage. My Web Developer Tools show me that stored Data exists, but when I turn or reload the page I get my < span > fields empty.

```
    var insideSpanTags = document.getElementsByClassName("spanEvent");//all my <spans> 
      insideSpanTags.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('Date');// I want my stored data to be shown there
```

So, how can I get my stored data inside < span > tags every time I refresh or reload the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop your selectors

```
var insideSpanTags = document.getElementsByClassName("spanEvent");

for(var i=0; i<insideSpanTags.length; i++){
      insideSpanTags[i].innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('Date');
}
```

cause `insideSpanTags` is an Array collection of all your elements.

---

Since you're using an Array of objects, you need to `JSON.stringify` your Array of objects into localStorage. Than to retrieve the values use `JSON.parse`:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vinugi/3/edit?html,js,console,output)***

```
var insideSpanTags = document.getElementsByClassName("spanEvent");
var events = [
    {
        'date': '7-1-2015',
        'event': 'Event Title',
        'participants': 'John, Robert',
        'description': 'Football'        
    },
    {
        'date': '23-1-2015',
        'event': 'Event Title 2',
        'participants': 'Peter, Rob',
        'description': 'Basketball'        
    },
];


// On Save, use this to store your events:
localStorage.evts = JSON.stringify( events );
// Now events are stored in LS


// After it's saved but also while first reading use:
var storedEvts = JSON.parse( localStorage.evts );
console.log( storedEvts );


// Just to test
storedEvts.forEach(function(el, idx){
  insideSpanTags[idx].innerHTML = el.date;
});

// Result:
//> 7-1-2015
//> 23-1-2015
```

Comment: That's it! Thanx! But can you tell me please, how can I get a particular data, because after I put the loop it shows me the same 'Date' data in each of <span> tags. And I'd like to see a unique data inside each of <span> tags. Like you create some events there (it's not what I created, it's just for explanation) http://jsfiddle.net/5d4vh891/
And then want it to be shown in its own cell (not the same event in each cell)

Comment: @AlexandrBelov you need to learn how to store object inside a localStorage and than parse it back to retrieve the desired values.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov from your Question there's no way to know what kind of data you're storing. As I can see you're storing a single `ID`'s element `value`, so your comment is a bit odd.

Comment: Comment edited. Read it, please.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov as I've said http://jsbin.com/vinugi/2/edit?html,js,console,output as you can see it's terribly easy.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov in Chrome, hit F12 and inspect LocalStorage under "Resources" tab. You'll see the localStorage.evts change while saving your data.